# jagged edges in glith animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, edges

I want to get the glitch effect in the animation, everything comes out, but there is one problem. The edges of the animation are jagged, I would like to get a uniform white background.

[image]

[image]

Blender file:

[File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AguzV3TWGlFehnb9Sev4BVw_yScF)

Comment: Please attach a .blend

Comment: I have only scene which this nodes.

Comment: I would like your .blend to speed up the answering process and make sure everything is exactly replicated. If you can't give the file for any reason, maybe consider making a small different example that we can fix

Comment: I add blend file. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image gets distorted and is smaller at the end than at the beginning the transparent background appears. To fix this I just added the background where there was none..

[image]

[image]